# Authentication with the requests library not working

Tags: python, post, python-requests, python-2.x

Trying to making HTTP Post, passing two params for authentication: `user,password`

```
import requests 
url = 'http://10.10.13.3:8000/api/login'
payload = {'user': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'}

response = requests.post(url,data=payload)
print response.url
print response.text
```

What's weird is, this code which is returning me, it's the same when I login with user/password wrong, but testing login on the website, it's working. Is this the right code to make post authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace `data` with `json`.
l
like this:

```
import requests 
url = 'http://10.10.13.3:8000/api/login'
payload = {'user': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'}

response = requests.post(url,json=payload)
print response.url
print response.text
```

Comment: `requests.post(url,json=payload)` like that?

Comment: @TMoraes yes (oops made a mistake in my answer, should look good now)

Comment: Great, it worked. But when I use json or data to send a payload?

Comment: I'm happy it worked! You have to use `json=` when you are sending a JSON string (As a rule of thumb, I myself always start by using `data=` and then try `json=` if I encounter any issues). for more info check out this [link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)